# Obex Client Session connect respose is OBEX_HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE(198)

Tags: java, android

I trying to develop an android app which can browse through folders via another paired android device.I am using blucove-android2 libraries

Used below codes

```
ClientSession conn = null;

 String btURL = "btgoep://806C1B3F2A83:0000110500001000800000805f9b34fb;authenticate=false;" +"encrypt=false;master=false;android=true";

       String obexUUIDs = "0x0008, 0x1105, 0x1106";   
      BlueCoveImpl.setConfigProperty(BlueCoveConfigProperties.PROPERTY_ANDROID_OBEX_UUIDS, obexUUIDs);           
BlueCoveImpl.setConfigProperty(BlueCoveConfigProperties.PROPERTY_ANDROID_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, String.valueOf(10));
        String folder = "media";
        try {                
            conn = (ClientSession) Connector.open(btURL);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e1) {
            Log.d("OBEX","Error Caught");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Target Header must be set to the Folder Browsing UUID:
        //F9EC7BC4-953C-11D2-984E-525400DC9E09.
        byte[] FBUiid = {(byte)0xF9,(byte)0xEC,(byte)0x7B,(byte)0xC4,(byte)0x95,(byte)0x3C,(byte)0x11,(byte)0xD2,
                (byte)0x98,(byte)0x4E,(byte)0x52,(byte)0x54,(byte)0x00,(byte)0xDC,(byte)0x9E,(byte)0x09};

        //Connect
        HeaderSet header = conn.createHeaderSet();
        header.setHeader(HeaderSet.TARGET, FBUiid );
        HeaderSet response = conn.connect(header);
```

I am receiving response as 198(OBEX_HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE). After this when I m calling 
HeaderSet result = conn.setPath(header, false, false), an IOexception session not connected is thrown.
Please query what would be the reason in getting response as 198.

Note : trying to create an android app not Java
Libraries Im using : bluecove-2.1.1-20101024.214840-60.jar,bluecove-android2-2.1.1-20101024.214840-1.jar

Comment: I found the solution String btURL = "btgoep://806C1B3F2A83:0000110600001000800000805f9b34fb;authenticate=false;" +"encrypt=false;master=false;android=true"; this URL should be used.

Comment: But in android phones OBEX FTP service wont start automatically. Is there any way we can start if from my app remotely